# Sending gRPC request in node without .proto file

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, grpc, protobuf.js

I have a NextJS with Typescript application. I want to connect to a running gRPC server and send gRPC requests to the server. I do not have access to the .proto file, but I know the server address, service name, messages names and fields. I can't find any information which allows me to send requests without having a .proto file in my NextJS folder structure. How can I achieve this desired functionality?

Here are two things that may help guide a solution:

1. I have access to the raw contents of a .proto file. I access this via the Gitlab API, but I cannot have the .proto file in my application. I have created a parser to parse this into an object so that I have access to the services, messages and fields.
2. Each gRPC connection (I don't know the terminology) is wrapped in reflection, so I can use reflection on the gRPC server. However, I have not found anything that allows me to do that without having the .proto file.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What exactly is the constraint here? Is it that you can't have a file with `.proto` in its name?

Comment: I'm not able to have the .proto file definition in my project, and because of this, I don't know how to establish a connection with the gRPC server/send requests with the correct services/messages without hardcoding them in. I want that to be dynamically.

Comment: What about a JSON file that contains the same information that the `.proto` file contains? Would you be able to use that?

Comment: The whole point is to not have any information of what proto messages there are before connecting to the server. I want to eventually dynamically create input fields for each field and send a request to the server.